# Hive metastore in hdfs

Tags: hive, hdfs

Usually you store the metadata onto a jdbc compliant database like mysql. Is it possible to keep it in hdfs somehow like in Hbase. Did not find anything useful in the wikis. Thanks.

Comment: Can we use hbql to store hive metadata in hdfs by using hbase? I understand you need a jdbc compliant driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do as neither HDFS nor HBase support a proper JDBC interface yet, as is demanded by Hive's current metastore mechanisms.